# I have a php form mailer script that returns a text message to browser. Need .php code to redirect to html page

Tags: php, html, redirect, contact-form

this is the HTML PARTIAL CODE….

```
  <input type="hidden" name="recipient   value="msheree@msascodesignsolutions.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Submission" /> 
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="thankyou.html" />
  <input type="hidden" name="projectinquiries" value="projectinquiries">
  <div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="mailto:email@emailaddress.com?Subject=Hello, %20Interested%20In%20A%20Quote" target="_top" role="button">Contact</a>
  <input class="btn btn-default" type="reset" value="Reset">
  <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">
  …..
```

This is the .php file. It works fine. But I don't want a text message displayed in the browser. I want to redirect to a .html page called "thankyou.html". I changed web hosting companies to save money. From godaddy.com to hostgator.com and hostgator is incompetent to migrate my files and have the form working. I don't know .php. Please help me.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "msheree@msascodesignsolutions.com";

$email_subject = "Your email subject line";

function died($error) {

    // your error code can go here

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";

    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    die();

}



// validation expected data exists

if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

}



$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid. <br />';

}

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.  <br />';

}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

died($error_message);

}

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {

  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<!-- The above message displays in the browser. Please tell me what code and  exactly where to place it to redirect to a page called "thankyou.html" instead of getting the below message in the browser -->

<?php

}

?>
```

I don't want the above message seen, but to redirect to a html page instead.

Comment: is this the entirety of your PHP script? There is nothing to suggest _Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon._ would ever appear.

Comment: Your right, it got cut off.

Comment: Sorry….its // create email headers
 
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
 
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

 
?>
 
 
 
<!-- include your own success html here -->
 
 
 
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
 
 
 
<?php
 
}
 
?>

Comment: It looks like you're setting up a company called "msascodesignsolutions", so isn't it worth you knowing some PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned you don't know PHP, I'll spare some of the technical details here.

Place this at the end of your PHP script within the PHP tag replacing the URL with the URL you want to link to:

```
header('Location: http://www.msascodesignsolutions.com/thankyou.html');
```

So the last few lines should read like this:

```
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
header('Location: http://www.msascodesignsolutions.com/thankyou.html');

?>
```

This is the best, cleanest solution. Based on the PHP script you provided, I see no reason this would fail. However if for some reason you get a message like this:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent ...

You might consider creating the redirect in Javascript embedded in your HTML like so:

```
<!-- include your own success html here -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://www.msascodesignsolutions.com/thankyou.html"
</script>
```

This is a worse solution than the one using only PHP, but it will save you from having to make more significant changes to your PHP.

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Thank you Soooo much!

Comment: It Worked! Thank you again HPierce! I thank God for you! Be blessed.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Would you accept the answer as the solution to your question (check mark under the score)?

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually redirect is by adding a $redirect variable that I can then call on at the end of the script running. So for example: At the very top of the page or script I add.

```
$redirect = header('Location: fileNameOfPageYouWantToRedirectTo.php');
```

This has to be the first thing that runs or it will create an error is what I have experienced.

Then I run the script and at the end of the script I call on the following variable before closing the query. I would just add the "thankyou" page file name to the header function submitted at the top.

```
$redirect;
```

This however will not allow you to add a message such as "form was submitted" as it will redirect before the message gets out in the script or better said if the message is created, it redirects so fast that the visitor cannot see it(gets completely skipped) since you are redirecting to a thank you page, you're all set, no need to worry about the Javascript. You can also choose to dynamically generate the redirect link if you want to use a common file for more than one form to submit and make the redirect link change based on the current link to the form they are filling out. I assume it will be more efficient if you want to reuse it.